# How to statically link OpenSSL with my app in Xcode?

Tags: cocoa, openssl, xcode4.2, osx-lion

I am using a third party code which uses OpenSSL Crypto library. Since OSX 10.7 Apple has deprecated the use of OpenSSL in favor of their own solution.

Since I have no experience in Crypto coding, I cannot port the third party code to use Common Crypto. So to safeguard against the possibility that Apple may later drop OpenSSL, is there a way to statically link it with my app in Xcode?

I added the part 'in Xcode' since I am new to Xcode too, so when you tell me something like 'put flag X' then please also explain from where in Xcode interface I can put that 'flag X'. Thanks for reading this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally found a good source.

1. This blog post contains a lot of links and information - http://programmer-in-paradise.blogspot.com/2011/07/how-to-build-openssl-in-xcode.html
2. For just following this one, did the trick - https://github.com/sqlcipher/openssl-xcode

Answer (score 1):

Here's a brilliant resource on the issue. [here](http://receigen.etiemble.com/guides-openssl.html) . The simplest thing to do is use cocoapods and then follow the rest of the instructions.