# Include OpenSSL in CocoaTouch Application

Tags: cocoa, openssl

How do I include OpenSSL in my Cocoa Swift Application. And how can I use it in Command Line Applications? I dont want to use a Pod for it.

Any ideas?

Comment: Your questions are kind of broad and don't really have the details for us to give you a useful answer. You should probably start a Cocoa Swift Application, and then ask specific questions when you encounter problems.

Comment: I guess for starters, see [Using OpenSSL cocoa pod in iOS project](http://stackoverflow.com/q/34804890), [How to include OpenSSL on an iOS project in a way that works](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23955003), [How to statically link OpenSSL with my app in Xcode?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9342081), [XCode linking to OpenSSL library](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20448909), etc...

Comment: When I write Cocoa Application I mean a mac application, not iphone.
In xcode `libssl.tbd`and `libcrypto.tbd` are available as dynamic library. Can I use them? And import the header from openssl lib?

Comment: *"When I write Cocoa Application I mean a mac application, not iphone..."* - but you tagged it with iOS? Perhaps you should remove the iOS tag, and add a macosx tag?